# Multitasking swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I want to perform a function, which should repeat it's content every 60 seconds. This function should be called 60 times with a start delay of 1 second per function call.
So all in all, after 1 minute, the function has called 60 times and every second I get an update from one function, because the functions repeat their content after 60 seconds.
I would use a background thread for the function calls like this:

```
func callerfunc() {

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    var callerhelper = 0
    let timer2 = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
    callerhelper += 1
    if callerhelper > 60 {
    timer.invalidate()
    }
    else {
    syncfunction()
    print("syncfunc called every second until 1 minute")
    }
    }
}

let runLoop = RunLoop.current
runLoop.add(timer2, forMode: .default)
runLoop.run()

}
}

func syncfunction {

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
let timer3 = Timer(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true) { time in
print("task performed every 60 sec")
}

let runLoop = RunLoop.current
runLoop.add(timer3, forMode: .default)
runLoop.run()




}


}
```

But the code does not work the right way. Is the multithreading idea right here? How can I improve my code?

Comment: What does “But the code does not work the right way” mean?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. You want one thread to run every one second, and you want another thread to run every 60 seconds?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree : no, one thread starts 60 times one function with a delay of 1 sec and the function itself repeats its content every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Playground.

```swift
import Foundation

func callerfunc() {
  var callerhelper = 0
  let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
    callerhelper += 1
    if callerhelper == 60 {
      print("task performed every 60 sec")
      callerhelper = 0
    }
    else {
      print("syncfunc called every second until 1 minute. \(callerhelper)")
    }
  }
}

callerfunc()
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community—and better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: ok.The code should call a function 60 times with a delay of one second between each function call. And the function itself should repeat it's content every 60 seconds.                       So in the end, 60 instances of the same function are running, but asynchronous with a one second delay

Comment: To make it more clearly:
func_instance_1 is running 
--------after one sec-------------
func_instance_2 is running
.
.
---after 60 seconds---- 
func_instance_60 is running
AND func_instance_1 is repeating it's code
---after 61 sec---
 func_instance_2 is repeating it's code
---and so on-------